# Xcode - Storyboards - no leaks, but Live Bytes grows and grows and grows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, instruments, storyboard

Good Evening Developers.

I have made a little view switcher via storyboards, no big code, just two IBOutlets (UIButtton), for switching the views.

If I use Instruments, there is no memory leaks, but the Live Bytes keep growing when I press the buttons.

What do I do, to prevent this little grow-problem?

/Morten

Comment: Show us code or something related to the problem? maybe at the point the allocation occurs?

Comment: Can you show the IBAction code that handles the button clicks?

Comment: I don't have a code for that handles the click, storyboard handle that for me. I have only made a IBOutlet UIButton *myButton, and then the property and synthesize, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are testing with zombies enabled, disable them.

after that, use heap growth analysis (mark heap) in instruments to find out where the growths are (and the objects) over a period of time you define.

Comment: If you are running in Instruments, then click the info/detail button the allocations tool's track. you will see some checkboxes which will e/dis-able some features.

Comment: Now i'am really confused - What do you mean by Zombies may not be released?

Comment: @Morten when you run with zombies enabled, you can specify that they should never be freed. that is, they are intentionally leaked in order to detect possible future messages to deallocated instances. therefore, you want zombies disabled when you are analyzing heap growth.

Comment: Detect zombies is unchecked in my Allocations but I'm still getting this issue.